# Update MongoDB in Mongoose with two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and couldn't for some reason find anything in the documentation (Maybe I looked in the wrong places).

I got two arrays, say:

ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]

values = [12, 33, 44, 11]

Currently I am looping through the list ids and am updating the DB for each entry which seems incredibly inefficient:

For that I am using an object for each iteration (Simplified):

```
update['values']['duration'] = values[i];
```

This is how I insert into the DB

```
await CollectionName.updateOne({ids: ids[i]}, {$set: update});
```

Any pointers? Thanks! :)

Edit:
Example 2:

```
ids = [4, 7, 9]

values = [
{"array":
    "preference" : "test",
    "1Duration" : 55,
    "2Duration" : 66
},
{"array":
    "preference" : "test",
    "1Duration" : 22,
    "2Duration" : 33
},
{"array":
    "preference" : "test",
    "1Duration" : 78,
    "2Duration" : 11
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { },      //This is where you could insert into a spesific record                    
                    { $push: { ids , values  },
                    (err) => {
                         if (err) throw console.log('found errors');
                            console.log('record created')

                });
```

Comment: I dont' want to update one document, but many at a time, based on the id array...

Comment: the findOneAndUpdate also inserts into documents. With my lines of code you can push ids and values onto your mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$in` operator in this case.

```
await CollectionName.updateMany({ids: {$in: ids}}, {$set: update});
```

Comment: Ok test this code with any other property rather than ids. It will work. So i am sure there is issue with the conversion of ids to ObjectId.

Comment: Please see my updated example 2. I want to update my db in one go, using two arrays. So Mongo should find the document with the unique id 4 and update the "Array" document/array with "preference" : "test",
    "1Duration" : 55,
    "2Duration" : 66

As I understand, $in looks for a match, out of the whole array, and doesn't cycle through, right?